# Sort Objectsdictionnary

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have a tableview that contains multiple sections, grouped by an attribute of my object (date) I try to sort the tableview according to the value of date.I created a function for that , but I get an error  :

```
- (void)sortObjectsDictionnary:(NSArray *)arrayObjects
{
//this is my nsdictionnary
    [objects removeAllObjects]
//this is nsmutableaaray that contains dats
    [objectsIndex removeAllObjects];

    NSMutableSet *keys = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];

    for(int i=0;i<[arrayObjects count];i++){
        Task *myTask=[arrayObjects objectAtIndex:i];

//curentsection contains my objects whith dates
            NSMutableArray *currentSection = [objects objectForKey:taskDate];

            if (currentSection == nil)
            {
                [keys addObject:taskDate];

                currentSection = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

                [objects setObject:currentSection forKey:taskDate];


            }

            // we add objet to the right section
            [currentSection addObject:myTask];

    }
    [dateFormatter release];


    for (id element in keys) 
    { 
        [objectsIndex addObject:element];

        NSMutableArray *currentSection = [objects objectForKey:element];

        //I get an error in this line
        [currentSection sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    }
```

Comment: Well, where is the error?

Comment: at this line : [currentSection sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: it crashs, because  [currentSection sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]; I think it is used to compare String Value

Comment: This is not an Xcode question.

Comment: Crashes with what error?

Comment: (That is some really convoluted code!!)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what the error message is and I am assuming the error message may be due to accessing NSMutableArray array object without initializing it. Try an alloc and init for array before 
       NSMutableArray *currentSection = [NSMutableArray]alloc]init];
       currentSection = [objects objectForKey:element];

```
    //I get an error in this line
    [currentSection sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Well it is purely a guess. Post your error message if this not works.

Bharath

Comment: No it is included in the syntax of sorting an nsarray !

Comment: The error is very likely something like `[NSMutableArray compare:] unrecognized selector`.